# JavaScript function return html object, how can I parse it?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an AngularJS (1.4) application and I'm trying to manipulate a input type="number" through a directive.
I have to use type="number" because with type="tel" on iOs the character "." does not appear in the keyboard and this make impossibile to insert decimals number.

The goal is to make the user insert maximum 3 digits before the "." and maximum 2 digits after. The number of dots must not exceed one. That's the format I want in my input field.
The problem is that if I pass I print the variable this.value in the directive, it doesn't contain any ".".

Here's the html code:

```
<input required type='number' limit-to-number="3" number-of-decimals="2" ng-required="true" ng-model="invoice.price">
```

and here's the directive:

```
directive("limitToNumber", [function() {
      return {
          restrict: "A",
          link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
              var limit = parseInt(attrs.limitToNumber);
              var number_of_decimals = parseInt(attrs.numberOfDecimals);
              var digit_array = [];

              angular.element(elem).on("keydown", function(e) {

                console.log(this);

              });
          }
      };
  }]).
```

I tried different approaches, the main problem is that this.value does not contain ".".
For example if the input in the form is "12":

```
console.log(this.value) // -> 12
```

But if the input in the form is "......12.....":

```
console.log(this.value) // -> "" empty string
```

But I noticed that printing just "this" return the whole html of the input:

```
<input required type='number' limit-to-number="3" number-of-decimals="2" ng-required="true" ng-model="invoice.price" name="price" aria-invalid="false">
    #shadow-root (user-agent)
        <div id="text-field-container" pseudo="-webkit-textfield-decoration-container">
            <div id="editing-view-port">
                <div id="inner-editor">12.</div>
...
```

In the div with id="inner-editor" I can see the exact value of the input field. The problem now is that this is not working:

```
console.log(this.findElementById("inner-editor")); // -> Uncaught TypeError: this.getElementById is not a function
```

How can I extract that div value from the object "this" ?

﻿

Comment: this.value is empty cause the input is type numer

Comment: Are you sure that type number supports dots

Comment: Yes because I can insert them! The problem is that with type="string" on mobile it doesn't show the number pad (poor ux experience), and with type="tel" on iPhone is impossible to insert a dot (poor functionaliy experience). That's why I'm trying to use type="number"

Comment: I don't see a problem. `12` does not contain a dot but you expect the value to contain one? `......12....` is not a number but you expect to get the value anyway? The model is always a number. What you want to do with that number is up to you.

Comment: The problem is that I must not allow the user to insert more than one "."

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" max="999.99" min="0" required />
```

Of course you must validate input of user after submit (angular form validation foe example).

Comment: This doesn't prevent the user to insert input different from what I want for example : 11111.111111 or number higher than 999

Comment: But field with out of range input won`t be validating so user don`t submit them. You should always validate your input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.directive('limitToNumber', function () {
 return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
            // inputValue variable will contain the input box value
            var limit = parseInt(attrs.limitToNumber);
            var number_of_decimals = parseInt(attrs.numberOfDecimals);
            var digit_array = [];

            if (inputValue == undefined) return '';

            // Your transformation code will be written here
            // Assign the transformed value to transformedInput variable
            var transformedInput = '';

            if (transformedInput !== inputValue) {
                // This will update the input box
                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                modelCtrl.$render();
            }

            return transformedInput;
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: Almost there, I just need to intercept the keypressed because if I'm reaching the limit I would do something like: e.preventDefault(). How can I do the same in this case? Getting the value AND the keypressed?

Comment: By the way the inputValue returned in the directive is not registering all the ".", still the same problem: input "12." - inputValue "12." but input "12....." inputValue ""

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Can you provide me a fiddle?